# WPF: call HTML file from the application

Tags: html, wpf, call

I have created the program help as an HTML file.
Now I want to call it from the application.
On the Internet you can find the solution here:

```
Process.Start ( "Hilfe.html");
```

This does not work for me! Nothing happens when I call that.
Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: do you want to open in user's default browser?

Comment: And where should Process.Start find this so called Hilfe.html ? I would say you have to specify the full path and it should work

Comment: Thank you. I tried this:  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Markus Lemcke\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\WPFTexteditor\\WPFTexteditor\\Hilfe.html"); but the same result! No Browser windows appears!

Comment: what happens if you open a Cmd console window and type "Start Hilfe.html"?

Comment: it works! The website is opened in the standard browser!

Comment: How can I do this from my Application?

Comment: Process.Start("fullpath\\Hilfe.html") should work. The first one Process.Start("Hilfe.html") should throw a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified. If the browser is not starting and you are not getting any exception, perhaps you should set a breakpoint and debug to see if you even hit it.

Comment: this call Works:   Process.Start(@System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Hilfe.html");